# How do I make a struct program in which I can store an infinite amount of data so that everytime you want you can add another product to the list?

Tags: c++

i have a school assignment where i need to create a Wine inventory System with which one can always add different Items to the list for example if you work in something like a warehouse and you get a new product which one needs to put into the system, rather than changing the code you just type it into the console.

The program works however i can only add 3 different types of wine because i only made three structs

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Wine1 {
    string name;
    string year;
    string place;
    string price;
} wine;
void printwine(Wine1 wine);

struct Wine2 {
    string name;
    string year;
    string place;
    string price;
} wine2;
void printwine2(Wine2 wine2);

struct Wine3 {
    string name;
    string year;
    string place;
    string price;
} wine3;
void printwine3(Wine3 wine3);


int main()
{
    string str;
    cout << "Please enter the data of the First wine: " << endl;
    cout << "Enter name: " ;
    getline(cin,wine.name);
    cout << endl << "Enter year: ";
    getline(cin, wine.year);
    cout << endl << "enter country of creation: ";
    getline(cin, wine.place);
    cout << endl << "enter price: ";
    getline(cin, wine.price);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the data of the Second wine: " << endl;
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    getline(cin, wine2.name);
    cout << endl << "Enter year: ";
    getline(cin, wine2.year);
    cout << endl << "enter country of creation: ";
    getline(cin, wine2.place);
    cout << endl << "enter price: ";
    getline(cin, wine2.price);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the data of the third wine: " << endl;
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    getline(cin, wine3.name);
    cout << endl << "Enter year: ";
    getline(cin, wine3.year);
    cout << endl << "enter country of creation: ";
    getline(cin, wine3.place);
    cout << endl << "enter price: ";
    getline(cin, wine3.price);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "your entered data: " << endl;
    printwine(wine);
    cout << endl;
    printwine2(wine2);
    cout << endl;
    printwine3(wine3);

}
void printwine(Wine1 wine) {
    cout << "Wine1" << endl;
    cout << "the name is: " << wine.name << endl;
    cout << "it's year is: " << wine.year << endl;;
    cout << "its country of creation is: " << wine.place << endl;;
    cout << "it's price is: " << wine.price << endl;
}

void printwine2(Wine2 wine2) {
    cout << "Wine2" << endl;
    cout << "the name is: " << wine2.name << endl;
    cout << "it's year is: " << wine2.year << endl;;
    cout << "its country of creation is: " << wine2.place << endl;;
    cout << "it's price is: " << wine2.price << endl;;
}

void printwine3(Wine3 wine3)
{
    cout << "Wine3" << endl;
    cout << "the name is: " << wine3.name << endl;
    cout << "it's year is: " << wine3.year << endl;;
    cout << "its country of creation is: " << wine3.place << endl;
    cout << "it's price is: " << wine3.price << endl;;
}
```

Comment: Why are you making 3 different `Wine` structs that have the exact same members?  One `Wine` struct shoul;d be able to represent any type of wine.

Comment: that it outputs 3 different products                                                                      
 ie your entered data:
Wine1
the name is: wine1
it's year is: 2000
its country of creation is: France
it's price is: 200

Wine2
the name is: Wine2
it's year is: 2002
its country of creation is: Italy
it's price is: 200

Wine3
the name is: Wine3
it's year is: 1999
its country of creation is: France
it's price is: 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should notice that you are creating 3 structs that are the same.

So this could be made easily with a vector of structs or an array.

I would declarate: `vector<Wine> wines(3);` Where 3 is the number of wines you'll have.

And to put the values you can simply use: `wines[i].name` Where 'i' is the wine you want to edit.

I suppose you already know loops, because that's what you have to use.

Also, if you want to use vectors, you have to include it with `#include <vector>`

Comment: welcome. good answer. possible improvement: start with an empty vector and add new wines via .push_back(); i'd discourage using array when the size is not known in advance.